# How to persist data in a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, persistence

I'm developing a ruby gem for use in rails app.
The gem need to "initialize" using live data from a webservice.

But this initialization is a long process, and i want to save the initialization data somewhere. Where should i save it?

I could save it in the parent rails app database, but i would need to create tables and migrations, and this isn't ideal.

I'm thinking of using a text file or redis database inside the gem folder... Is this a good practice?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveSupport` has several [`Cache`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache.html) classes. You could for example use the default `Rails.cache`:

```
Rails.cache.write('my-gem-initialization-data', 'foo bar baz')
```

If you need more flexibility, you could provide an initializer, something like:

```
# config/initializers/my_gem.rb
MyGem.configure do |config|
  config.cache = Rails.cache
  config.cache_key = 'my-gem-initialization-data'
end
```

Comment: But they are not persistent, only ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore is persistent, and i still need a location to save it...

Comment: @Grey I see, but you said _"i want to cache the initialization data"_ :-)

Comment: eheh, ok i clarified that.

Comment: @Grey IMO it would be a bad design to hard-code the location or caching mechanism or to rely on the presence of a particular system (not even a filesystem, think of Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem)). The initializer approach would allow the user of your gem to set an appropriate cache store and in case of a `FileStore` also the location.

Comment: @Grey just to be clear: the initializer would go into the Rails app, not your gem.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that it is perfectly fine to expect the user to generate and run a migration as part of the setup of your gem.

In fact this is quite common: Look at well known gems like devise (that needs certain columns on the users table) or paper_trail (that needs a table in the database to store versions)

On the other hand your alternatives are not always feasible. You cannot expect the user to have a redis database configured (most of my apps don't use redis at all) and some environments (like Heroku for example) do not allow to write files persistently.

Comment: Maybe an sqlite database then? I won't have to use heroku.

Comment: A sqlite database would require the user to change its deploy scripts. The deploy script needs to ensure that the database is still available after the deploy of a new version of the app. Furthermore even if you do not use Heroku (or another file system that is readonly) the user of your gem might want to use it on such a system. I think sqlite is not an option.